# sending client side resized image with post

Tags: javascript, image, post

With Javascript I resize an image on client side succesfully, but I can't give the result back to the file input.

```
<input id="file" name="userfile" type="file" />
```

I resized and get a very large text data

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAYAAA...
```

I dont know how to give back to the file input, or send with post.

The

```
f.value = data;
```

doesn't work.

I tried to put the data in a text field, but larger text than about 130k is not accepted by the server, but the resized images are usually bigger than this. I didnt find how to change that restriction, or how to post the large data.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: "but larger text than about 130k is not accepted by the server". Could you upload large images to the server? If not, there's no option with this server except, maybe, sending it in severals parts

Comment: Yes, i can upload a lot larger files, but i cant transform my data (data:image/png;base64,IVBORw0...) back to a file to upload as file.

Answer (score 1):

Using a text field or a hidden field, and send the form as a POST request would be the correct way to send it.

If you send the form as a GET, the data will be put in the URL, and that would be very limiting on the data size. A limit of 130 kb sounds about right.

Sending POST data is only limited by how large a request the server will accept, and this is normally a lot more than 130 kb. The default for a Windows server for example is 4 MB.

Comment: I do it with post, but some server settings (maybe suhosin?) doesnt allow me to send more than 130k data in a textfield. The maximum file size is set to more-than-enough, but i cant transform my image base64 data back to file to upload.

Comment: @GeorgeGebauer: Yes, Suhosin seems to limit the request values. This might be useful: http://www.webmastertalkforums.com/blogs/jordan/401-suhosin-request-post-get-character-length-limit-max_value_length.html

Comment: 130kb is too much for GET. limit is 2-4 kb usually

Comment: @kirilloid: That's the limit set by some browsers (e.g. IE), and indeed the size that you should keep it below to be safe, but some browsers allow much more. 130 kb could very well be the limitation of some specific browser, or some specific web server.

Comment: @Guffa Thx the suhosin forum link, it was very helpful. But i cant change the settings, so i cant solve the problem like this. Must be a solution somehow to post the data. It would be great if i could change the browsed original file to my resized one in <input type='file'>. But i dont know how. Tnx

Comment: @GeorgeGebauer: You can't put anything in the file upload control, for security reasons. There is a technique that I have seen used for drag-and-drop uploaders, where you can send a file using Javascript. That might be possible to use. It's not supported in all browsers, though.